# Supabase Twilio Phone Auth

Tags: react-native, twilio, supabase

I am building a react native app using Supabase with phone auth on Android emulator.
I have set my twilio and Supabase up, but when I call supabase.auth.signUp(), it does not send a OTP to my phone number.
This is my code:

async function signInWithPhoneNumber() {
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(
{ phone: '+61 xxx xxx xxx', 
password: 'some-password' })  
 setConfirm(data);

console.log(data)
if (error) { 
console.log('error') 
return } }

And I just have a button that calls this function. The 'xxx xxx xxx' is a placeholder for my actual number. I tried using the provided Twilio phone number as well but to no success. My twilio account is working well, as i was able to send a message from Twilio to my real phone. And I correctly put in the phone auth details for Supabase.
My log for the 'data' gives me: {"session": null, "user": null}
And if i was to log the actual error, it gives me: [AuthRetryableFetchError: Network request failed]

Anyone know the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to see if you can sign up a user with an email address and a password?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use phone authentication with password: only OTP. Have you tried the following:

```
await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
  phone: '+61xxxxxxxxx',
})

await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({
  phone: '+61xxxxxxxxx',
  token: 'xxxxxx',
  type: 'sms'
})
```

see also:

- https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithotp
- https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-verifyotp